# stack trace : weka.core.WekaException: weka.classifiers.functions.SMO: Not enough training instances with class labels (required: 1, provided: 0)!

Tags: java, weka

When i try to print the number of instances it shows me 0(zero). But when i manually choose the ARFF file using Weka API there are 565 instances in my training data.I would like to find where the error is. Thank you.

```
private static void build_model() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try{

            // load data    
            ArffLoader loader = new ArffLoader();
            loader.setFile(new File("D:\\MAIN PROJECT\\data.arff"));
            Instances structure = loader.getStructure();
            structure.setClassIndex(structure.numAttributes() - 1);
            System.out.println("Attributes : "+structure.numAttributes());
            System.out.println("Instances : "+structure.numInstances());

            // train SMO
            System.out.println("Before creating smo object");
            SMO smo = new SMO();
            System.out.println("SMO object created");
            smo.buildClassifier(structure);
            System.out.println("Classifier build");
            Instance current;
            while ((current = loader.getNextInstance(structure)) != null){
                smo.buildClassifier((Instances) current);
            }
            System.out.println(smo);
            System.out.println("\nModel build successfully");
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("\nstack trace : " + e);
            }

        }
```

Output :

Attributes : 1154
Instances : 0
Before creating smo object
SMO object created

stack trace : weka.core.WekaException: weka.classifiers.functions.SMO: Not enough training instances with class labels (required: 1, provided: 0)!

Comment: how are you doing the automatic process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `getDataSet()` instead of `getStructure()`

Comment: Thank you now it showed me correct number of instances in my training data but now i encounter a new exception. Please help me.....stack trace : java.io.IOException: Cannot mix getting Instances in both incremental and batch modes

Comment: ok how many times are you seeing this exception? I mean when you run the code, you see it once or twice?

Comment: After removing the loop it worked well as i posted the working code below.. Thank you... And do you know how to test this model? By giving a single instance??

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly working.

```
private static void build_model() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{

        // load data    
        ArffLoader loader = new ArffLoader();
        loader.setFile(new File("D:\\MAIN PROJECT\\data.arff"));
        Instances structure = loader.getDataSet();
        structure.setClassIndex(structure.numAttributes() - 1);
        System.out.println("Attributes : "+structure.numAttributes());
        System.out.println("Instances : "+structure.numInstances());

        // train SMO
        System.out.println("Before creating smo object");
        SMO smo = new SMO();
        System.out.println("SMO object created");
        smo.buildClassifier(structure);
        System.out.println("Classifier build");
        System.out.println(smo);
        System.out.println("\nModel build successfully");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("\nstack trace : " + e);
        }

    }
```